# How can string be converted to number in xceptor

Tags: string, numbers

What enrichment/formula is required to convert a string to number in Xceptor. I tried FormatNumber

Comment: Please consider adding more tags to your question and also more details on what you did so far and which error you are facing (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a calculation enrichment and then use the DECIMAL([string field]) function - description for this is - DECIMAL: Converts a text string to a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `INTEGER` function to convert a string to an integer

For example, TestInteger = INTEGER("7600")

More information can be found here [Xceptor Docs - INTEGER Function](https://docs.xceptor.com/CoreConfiguration/Configuration/Common%20Tools/Function.html#integer)